# std::ranges::remove still not suported / broken on clang trunk when using libstdc++?

Tags: c++, clang, std-ranges

Works fine on gcc trunk, but not on clang trunk, both with libstd++.

Or am I missing something exceedingly obvious?

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KKr7bh89G)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& v) {
    for (auto&& e: v) os << e << " "; 
    return os;
}

int main() {
    auto ints = std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << ints << "\n";
    auto [first, last] = std::ranges::remove(ints, 3);
    ints.erase(first, last);
    std::cout << ints << "\n";
}
```

gcc is clean. clang gives a WALL OF ERRORS, complaining about missing "__begin".

UPDATE: If I use `-stdlib=libc++` then clang says "never heard of it", so I guess they are just not there yet.

[new Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KKr7bh89G)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a Clang bug, affecting ranges when using libstdc++, see [this issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44178) with the underlying cause which is still open and other issues linked to it as duplicates with examples how it affects ranges with libstdc++. There seems to have been some work on it about two weeks ago.

In libc++ `std::ranges::remove` does not seem to be implemented yet as you noticed and as stated on its [status page](https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Ranges.html) for ranges implementation.

Comment: Yeah. that's a good find. With my limited key words I was not getting any of that. Hopefully will get sorted soon.

Comment: As an update, the linked issue has now been closed and should be in clang 16.
The godbolt example also works on clang trunk, but errors on clang 15.